# Can I set a minimal time required between clicks for a double-click?

Tags: windows-8, mouse, double-click

This might be a bit of a weird question and usually easily solvable, but company restrictions prevent me from doing this the easy way, so please bear with me.

In my office work-space I've been assigned a mouse to work with. This mouse unfortunately is slightly defective. Defective enough to be highly annoying but not defective enough to pass for a replacement. The main problem is:

**Sometimes when I single-click, the mouse sends 2 clicks in a row, resulting in a double-click**

This is highly annoying, for example it has caused me to close 2 windows instead of just the one I want multiple times. And as a programmer, when I want to place the cursor at a specific point in my code I accidentally select the whole line and start overwriting what I made before.

Of course I've consulted [Microsoft's Knowledge Base](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/266738) for this. Step 1:

> **Verify your clicking method:** Make sure that you are performing a true single physical click. A single-click occurs when you press and release a mouse button one time.

Well... Microsoft doesn't take my complaint very serious it seems. The article basically ends with me having to turn the mouse off and on again.

So I tried messing with the double-click speed settings in windows. But the only thing it really changes is the maximum delay between clicks for it to register a double-click. This doesn't solve my problem at all because the speed at witch these inputs are send are close to a few millisecond. And I still want to actually double-click when I want to.

I can only see 2 options that would fix my dilemma (and I prefer the latter):

1. Physically break the mouse - If my mouse literally doesn't work anymore, I can get a replacement, hopefully by the end of this day, probably by the end of the week.
2. Find a way to force a time delay between clicks to register as a double-click - the problem is caused by inputs that are being send a few milliseconds in a row. A human is pretty much physically restricted to having a clicking delay of about 100 milliseconds, if I can somehow filter out these false positives by enforcing a - let's say - 50 millisecond delay required before I can click again for a double click, that would solve my problem. In theory.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could fix this by social engineering.

Comment: I count that as a win for the mouse. I can't let the mouse win now. It's personal.

Comment: ... or... "I was just cleaning the button [with an entire bottle of water] now it doesn't work at all. What should I do?"  ;)

Comment: I like where this is going. Maybe the question should be how I can murder my mouse in the most "acceptable" way possible...

Comment: Your mouse is defective. Try cleaning the micro-switches with contact cleaner, if that doesn't help -- Easy: replace mouse. Hard: [replace micro-switches](http://superuser.com/questions/959298/how-to-change-microswitches-left-right-mouse-button-on-logitech-g700).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that question @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 it solved my problem!